# How to edit the font options in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4.6 with [the official font size and family plugin.](http://ckeditor.com/addon/font) Is it possible to change the font family option?

I am using fonts from Google Fonts and so I have the extra font files needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [font_names](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-font_names) configuration option.

> The list of fonts names to be displayed in the Font combo in the
>   toolbar. Entries are separated by semi-colons (';'), while it's
>   possible to have more than one font for each entry, in the HTML way
>   (separated by comma).
>
> A display name may be optionally defined by prefixing the entries with
>   the name and the slash character. For example, 'Arial/Arial,
>   Helvetica, sans-serif' will be displayed as 'Arial' in the list, but
>   will be outputted as 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'.

```
config.font_names =
    'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Verdana';

config.font_names = 'Arial;Times New Roman;Verdana';
```